# using a 2d array that keeps track of how many time the 'd' is in that location

Tags: c#

I have a 2d array that is moving the char 'd' around and everything that isn't a char has '*'. When the movement starts all locations are a zero.  Every time a move takes place, that location is incremented by 1. How do I increment the values at each spot?
My code:

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
  bool over = false;
  
  Console.Write("Enter city size: ");
  int size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  char [,] city = new char [size,size];
  int [,] counts = new int [size,size];

  CreateCity(city);
  Console.Clear();
  while(!over){
    ShowCity(city, counts);        
    Move(city, counts, ref over);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep((int)System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).TotalMilliseconds);
    if(!over){
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine();}
    }//end while

  Console.WriteLine("done");
}//end main 

public static void CreateCity(char [,] c){
  int rowLength = c.GetLength(0);
  int colLength = c.GetLength(1);
  for(int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < colLength; j++){
    c[i,j] = '*';}//end j
  }//end i
  c[rowLength/2,colLength/2] = 'D';
}//end CreateCity

public static void ShowCity (char [,] c, int [,] d){
  for(int i = 0; i < c.GetLength(0); i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < c.GetLength(1); j++){Console.Write("{0}\t",c[i,j]);}
    Console.WriteLine();
  }}//end ShowCity

public static int GetDirection(){
  Random random = new Random();  
  int num = random.Next(-1,2);
  return num;
  }

public static void Move (char [,] c, int [,] d, ref bool done){
  int alocation = 0;
  int bloaction = 0;
  int anewLocation = 0;
  int bnewlocation = 0;
  int asize = c.GetLength(0);
  int bsize = c.GetLength(1);


  for(int i = 0; i < asize; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < bsize; j++){
    if (c[i,j] == 'D'){
    alocation = i;
    bloaction = j;
  }}}
  
  anewLocation = alocation+GetDirection();
  bnewlocation = bloaction+GetDirection();

  if (( anewLocation == -1 || anewLocation == asize ) || ( bnewlocation == -1 || bnewlocation == bsize )){
  done = true; 
  }//bounds if
  else{

  c[alocation,bloaction] = '*';
  c[anewLocation,bnewlocation] = 'D';
  
  }
}
}//end  class
```

produces

```
*   *   *   *   *
*   *   *   *   D
*   *   *   *   *
*   *   *   *   *
*   *   *   *   *
```

and the D started in the middle and moved so I want it to produce

```
*   *   *   *   *
*   *   *   1   D
*   *   1   2   1
*   *   *   1   1
*   *   *   *   *
```

so it changed to 1 if it the D moved there once. I have the    `int [,] counts = new int [size,size];` to hold the values I will use for the numbers but I would appreciate help on how to proceed

Answer (score 2):

The `Move()` method should change to something like this:

```cs
        else
        {
            d[alocation, bloaction]++;
            string countStr = d[alocation, bloaction].ToString();
            c[alocation, bloaction] = countStr[countStr.Length - 1];
            c[anewLocation, bnewlocation] = 'D';
        }
    }
}//end  class
```

I used `countStr[countStr.Length - 1]` because the city cells are characters and cannot hold the whole string. I think you'd better use `string[,]` instead of `char[,]`.